# C++ conditions based on runtime polymorphic object's class

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I'm trying to make some conditional actions depend on the type of polymorphic objects resolved at runtime.

Here is some pseudocode to illustrate what I mean:

```cpp
class Base {
   public:
   virtual ~Base(){}
} ;

class Foo : public Base {
   public:
   virtual ~Foo(){}
}; 

class Bar : public Base {
   public:
   virtual ~Bar(){}
};

int main() 
{
  std::vector<Base*> v;
  Base* A = new Foo();
  Base* B = new Bar();
  v.push_back(A); 
  v.push_back(B);  
 
  std::stack<Base*> s; 

  for (auto& ptr : v)
  {
    // push on stack if of type Foo, do nothing if of type Bar
  }
}
```

Here is an implementation of this idea in Java.:

```java
// for (...)
{
  if (component instanceOf Foo)
  {
    stack.push(component)
  }
}
```

What would be the correct way to implement this idea in C++?

Comment: Don't. Use virtual functions,

Comment: I could use a virtual function and pass my stack by reference, and the object would either add itself to the stack or do nothing depending on the runtime resolution. But suppose I'm not the author of the code for Base, Foo and Bar.

Comment: Then you probably should either ask yourself whether you are using the library correctly, file a bug report to the author, or find a less broken library. Run-time type checks within an inheritance hierarchy have their place in the grand scheme of things, but this place is not in the business logic of an application. You can do that, but you almost never should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with [`dynamic_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast):

```
if (auto* fooptr = dynamic_cast<Foo*>(ptr); fooptr != nullptr)
{
    stack.push(fooptr);
}
```

This of course requires that the classes really are polymorphic, and have at least one `virtual` function (which should be the destructor).